# Rails and Postgresql how to sort with custom count? ORDER BY is ambiguous

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, named-scope

Relationship User has_many :kits

User model and named scope:

```
  scope :top5_users,
    joins(:kits).
    select("users.*, count(kits.id) AS kits_count").
    group("users.id, kits.id").
    order("kits_count DESC").
    limit(5)
```

Getting PG::Error: ERROR:  ORDER BY "kits_count" is ambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message implies you have a column in users called kits_count, possibly maintained by a callback. If so you could more easily just:

```
scope :top5_users,
    order("kits_count DESC").
    limit(5)
```

If not ...

Support for column aliases is mixed among RDBMS vendors, and you could probably use:

```
order("count(kits.id) desc")
```

If you knew the column number you could:

```
scope :top5_users,
    joins(:kits).
    select("count(kits.id) AS kits_count, users.*").
    group("users.id").
    order("1 DESC").
    limit(5)
```

Take the kits.id out of the group by or you'll get 1 for every count.

Comment: order("count(kits.id) desc") works. And yeah i removed kits.id from group_by, thank you for hitting me. But still not getting why cannot use the alias.

Comment: The error suggests that there are multiple columns projected from the query that are called "kits_count" -- do you have a column of that name in the users table?

Comment: Was double checking everything User.column_names.include?("kits_count") is false, Kit.column_names.include?("kits_count") is false. And there is no other association though 3rd table or something similar..

Comment: Well I'd just login to psql and run \d users; -- it's postgres' opinion of whether there's a column in the table called "kits_count" that is definitive. Could be that the error message is just a bit misleading though.

Comment: There is no such a column, hmm, maybe i am blind..:-) I tried to rename the alias "kits_count" to "kits_count_per_user" it worked also with ORDER, and because i am using that alias "kits_count" to print in view i was expecting to dont raise an error and see some value. But it raised error undefined kits_count. Thank you again.